# Block matrix with matrices along the diagonal and identity elsewhere

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

I am trying to find the determinant of a $N^2\times N^2$ matrix of the form
$$\boldsymbol{A} = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{A}_0^N & I_N & \cdots & I_N \\
  I_N & \boldsymbol{A}_1^N & \cdots & I_N \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  I_N & I_N & \cdots & \boldsymbol{A}_{N-1}^N 
 \end{pmatrix},$$
where $diag(\boldsymbol{A})=(\boldsymbol{A}_0^N,\boldsymbol{A}_1^N,...,\boldsymbol{A}_{N-1}^N)$, $\boldsymbol{A}_i^N$ is a $N\times N$ matrix and $N\times N$ identity matrices everywhere else. I saw a paper "DETERMINANTS OF BLOCK TRIDIAGONAL MATRICES" by Luca Guido Molinari where he lets $\Psi$ be a vector such that $$\boldsymbol{A}\Psi=0,$$ where the components of $\Psi$ are $\psi_k\in\mathbb{C}^N$, where $k=0,1,2,...,N-1$. In the paper in Lemma 1, he derives two boundary terms and one term which he transforms into a transfer matrix. With my case I get a series of equations of the form:
$$\boldsymbol{A}_0^N\psi_0+\psi_1+\cdots+\psi_{N-1}=0$$
$$\psi_0+\boldsymbol{A}_1^N\psi_1+\psi_2+\cdots+\psi_{N-1}=0$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\psi_0+\psi_1+\psi_2+\cdots+\boldsymbol{A}_{N-1}^N\psi_{N-1}=0.$$
I'm not sure if there is a way to turn this into a transfer type matrix. The only form I can find is
$$\psi_{k}\boldsymbol{A}_k^N+\sum_{j=0,j\neq k}^{N-1}\psi_j=0$$ for each $k$. I don't know if this is the way to go about solving this problem. I have tried row manipulation, and induction but still no luck, any pointers?

EDIT:
Let $\tilde{I}^N_j=diag(0,..,0,1,0,...,0)$ where the $1$ is in the $j+1$-th diagonal and is a $N\times N$ matrix. Therefore $$\boldsymbol{A}=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\tilde{I}^N_j\otimes\boldsymbol{A}^N_j+M_N\otimes I_N.$$ Let $$M_N = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 
 \end{pmatrix},$$ is a matrix with $diag(0,0,...,0)$ and ones everywhere else. Now, Let $P$ be such that $D=diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_N)=PM_NP^{-1}$. Therefore we have
$$\det(\boldsymbol{A})=\det\left((P\otimes I_N)(\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\tilde{I}^N_j\otimes\boldsymbol{A}^N_j+M_N\otimes I_N)(P^{-1}\otimes I_N)\right)=\det(\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}P\tilde{I}^N_jP^{-1}\otimes\boldsymbol{A}^N_j+D\otimes I_N).$$ To find $P$ and $P^{-1}$ we need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M_N$.

We need $$\det(M_N-\lambda I_N)=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -\lambda & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
  1 & -\lambda & \cdots & 1 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  1 & 1 & \cdots & -\lambda 
 \end{pmatrix}.$$ So, adding all the rows underneath row 1 to row 1 i.e., $r1+r2$, $r1+r3$... We end up with 
$$\det(M_N-\lambda I_N)=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -\lambda+N-1 & -\lambda+N-1 & \cdots & -\lambda+N-1 \\
  1 & -\lambda & \cdots & 1 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  1 & 1 & \cdots & -\lambda 
 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Now subtract from column 2, column 1, and from column 3 subtract column 1 etc. Therefore we have $$\det(M_N-\lambda I_N)=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -\lambda+N-1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  1 & -\lambda-1 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  1 & 0 & \cdots & -\lambda-1 
 \end{pmatrix},$$ Therefore $$\det(M_N-\lambda I_N)=(-\lambda+N-1)(-\lambda-1)^{N-1},$$ thus we have one eigenvalue $\lambda=N-1$ and $N-1$ eigenvalues $\lambda=-1$. Confirming we look at the trace, $Tr(M_N)=0$ and (using the same row and column manipulations) $\det(M_N)=(-1)^{N-1}(N-1)$, since $Tr(M_N)=\sum_{l}\lambda_l=(N-1)+\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}(-1)=N-1-(N-1)=0$ and $\det(M_N)=\prod_{l}\lambda_l=(N-1)(-1)^{N-1}$. Now we compute the eigenvectors. With $\lambda=N-1$, one finds the first eigenvector is $\boldsymbol{v}_1=(1,\cdots,1)^{T}$. Since we have degeneracies we have to be careful. Since for $\lambda=-1$ we only have one non-zero row and therefore $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_N=0$ where $\boldsymbol{v}=(x_1,\cdots,1,x_N)^{T}$ is an eigenvector. Thus we pick $\boldsymbol{v}_2=(1,-1,0,\cdots,0)^T$, $\boldsymbol{v}_3=(1,0,-1,0,\cdots,0)^T$,..., $\boldsymbol{v}_N=(1,0,0,\cdots, 0,-1)^T$. Therefore $P=(\boldsymbol{v}_1\hspace{2mm}\boldsymbol{v}_2\cdots\hspace{2mm}\boldsymbol{v}_N)$ is an $N\times N$ matrix, with columns as the eigenvectors $\boldsymbol{v}_i$. $P^{-1}$ is found by row manipulation as is $$P^{-1}=\frac{1}{N}\begin{pmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{u}_1   \\
  \boldsymbol{u}_2 \\
  \vdots    \\
  \boldsymbol{u}_N  
 \end{pmatrix},$$ where $\boldsymbol{u}_1=(1,...,1),\boldsymbol{u}_2=(1,1-N,1,..,1), \boldsymbol{u}_3=(1,1,1-N,1,..,1), ...,\boldsymbol{u}_N=(1,...,1,1-N)$ or when $j>1$ there is a $N-1$ in the $j$-th position of $u_j$ and ones everywhere else. Now, $$P\tilde{I}_jP^{-1}=\frac{1}{N}\boldsymbol{v}_{j+1}\boldsymbol{u}_{j+1},$$ so for example $$P\tilde{I}_1P^{-1}=\frac{1}{N}\boldsymbol{v}_2\boldsymbol{u}_2=\frac{1}{N}\begin{pmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{u}_2  \\
  -\boldsymbol{u}_2  \\
  \boldsymbol{0}\\
  \vdots    \\
  \boldsymbol{0}  
 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1-N & 1& \cdots & 1 \\
  -1 & N-1&-1 & \cdots & -1 \\
0 & 0&0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots&0  \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &0
 \end{pmatrix},$$ where $\boldsymbol{0}$ is a row of $N$ zeros.

Therefore
$$\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{N}\boldsymbol{v}_{j+1}\boldsymbol{u}_{j+1}\otimes\boldsymbol{A}^N_j+D_N\otimes I_N=\boldsymbol{L}.$$ This is as far as I've got, I now need to find the summation on the left hand side then take the determinant, I can find the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A}_j^N$ if that helps?

Comment: I am not sure why you expect to find a non-trivial $\Psi$. [Surely almost every choice of the matrices $A_i$ makes $A$ non-singular?]

Comment: I found something that helped on another post (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545557/finding-the-eigenvalues-of-a-3n-times-3n-block-matrix?rq=1), which I will put in an edit.

Comment: Things are certainly easier if the $A_i$ are all equal!

Comment: that would be easier, but the problem I have is a finite difference equation similar to the Hofstadter Hamiltonian, but with some extra conditions.

Comment: It's easier to calculate the eigenvalues of $M$ [omit the unnecessary subscripts!] $M+I$, the all-1's matrix has trace $N$ and rank 1, and clearly has an eigenvalue $N$ (with the all-1's vector as eigenvector). So its eigenvalues are $N$ (once) and $0$ ($N-1$ times.)

Comment: I am not convinced that $PI_j P^{-1}=I_j$. ($I_j$ is just the standard $E_{jj}$ isn't it?)

Comment: Also, by reversing the basis we can see that reversing the order of the $A_i$ makes no difference to the determinant (up to $\pm$). Your answer isn't symmetric in that way.

Comment: Do you mean $\tilde{I}_j$? When $N=2$ for example my $\tilde{I}^2_1 = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0  \\
  0 & 0  
 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\tilde{I}^2_2= 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0  \\
  0 & 1  
 \end{pmatrix}$, is this what you mean by your $I_j$?

Comment: Sorry I missed the bar. But we are indeed just speaking of some of the usual $E_{i,j}$ matrices. My point is that they don't commute with the matrix that diagonalises the all-1's matrix.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm looking into this now

Comment: For the case of a $2\times 2$ matrix $P\tilde{I}^2_0P^{-1}+P\tilde{I}^2_1P^{-1}=I$. I'm struggling to generalise this to an $N\times N$ matrix.

Comment: Yes, but that's just $P^{-1}IP=I$. We know $P$ explicitly, it is the matrix whose ${i,j}$ entry is $\zeta^{ij}$; and $P^{-1}=\bar{P}^{T}$: here $\zeta$ is a primitive $N$-root of unity, and I number the rows/cols from $0$. I feel there ought to be an expression for the determinant in terms of the determinants of the matrices $\sum_{j}\zeta^{ij}A_j$ or the matrices $\sum_{j}\zeta^{ij}(A_j - I)$.

Comment: I can find the eigenvalues of $A_j$ by solving the recurrence relation in the usual way, maybe I can simplify this by diagonalising $A_j$?

Comment: I have just edited my question and have found the eigenvalues and vectors of $M_N$ and have reduced the problem to a summation.